# Copy existing data to fill in missing data using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have daily returns data that is missing data from certain months.  Here is an example, `dt`,  similar to what the data looks like (real data is hundreds of rows and 24 to 36 months of data as columns):

```
    set.seed(1)
    mlist <- list(matrix( rnorm(4*30,mean=0,sd=1), 4, 30),matrix( 
      rnorm(8*31,mean=0,sd=1), 8, 31),matrix( rnorm(12*10,mean=0,sd=1), 12, 10))
    n <- max(sapply(mlist, nrow)) 
    dt <- as.data.table(do.call(cbind, lapply(mlist, function (x) 
      rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x)))))) 
    names(dt) <- paste0("d_",seq(as.Date("2017-11-01"), as.Date("2018-01-10"), by="days"))
    dt1 <- data.table(unique_id=paste0("x",1:12)) 
    dt <- cbind(dt1,dt)
```

Jan 2018 has data for all assets, Dec 2017 has data for 8 assets, and Nov 2017 has data for 4 assets.  Where data is missing, copy the data for each asset from the closest future month that has data.  So, for assets x5:x8, the missing Nov 2017 data would be filled by copying Dec 2017 data.  For assets x9:x12, the missing Nov 2017 and Dec 2017 data would be filled by copying the Jan 2018 data, over and over again until all the missing data is filled.  Typically, the data for the current, most recent month will only be for a partial month. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks so much.

Comment: I'd use `zoo::na.locf` but you can probably also use a rolling join.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment @Roland.  I was not familiar with `na.locf`.  Your comment put me on the path to a solution.  I appreciate your help.